# Issue in jquery code because of http and https in url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used the following jquery code in my app

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var __machform_url = 'http://registeriq.com/embed.php?id=45837';

var __machform_height = 1109;

</script>

<div id="mf_placeholder"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://registeriq.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://registeriq.com/js/jquery.ba-postmessage.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://registeriq.com/js/machform_loader.js"></script>

    </div>
```

It works fine when url of web application contains http but it does not work when url contains https. Actually we have two servers for the same web application, one contain http and another contain https. This has created a lot of issues!!! Please help...

Comment: You can omit the protocol, just use `src="//regi"`.

Comment: _You never know unless you try_

Comment: I have deployed the code without http on server. it still does not work.. Now it says on server with url "https" that https://registeriq.com/js/jquery.min.js could not be loaded because its actual server is  http://registeriq.com/js/jquery.min.js. Please see the difference in both url

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not clear how the `__machform_url` string is used, I would suspect it more than the script srcs.

Try :

```
var __machform_url = location.protocol + '//registeriq.com/embed.php?id=45837';
//or maybe
var __machform_url = '//registeriq.com/embed.php?id=45837';
//or maybe
var __machform_url = '/embed.php?id=45837';
```

In fact, that last form, omitting the protocol and domain, should work for the script srcs too.